# How to select a date in a datepicker 21 days from curreny date always with selenium java

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is my code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
    Date dt = new Date();
    Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
    cl.setTime(dt);;
    cl.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 21);
    dt=cl.getTime(); 
    String check_date = df.format(dt);
    System.out.println("the depature date is " +check_date);

    js.executeScript("document.getElementById('txtFromDatesFgt').value='check_date'");
```

When I run this code then date is stored in string and output will be displayed on console, but how do I send this string into   `.value='');`?

Comment: Can you also post your html where the datepicker is? Or post link to website which you are trying to test?

Comment: https://www.travelsouq.com/en

Comment: You don't need the quotes around `js.executeScript...value=check_date");`

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the HTML you can find an hidden input element for the date

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="*" id="txtFromDateFgt" name="StartDate" type="hidden" value="19/03/2020">
```

you can update the value of this field instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("txtFromDatesFgt"])).setAttribute("value", check_date);
```